# Why are decision trees and random forests scale invariant?

Tags: decision-trees, random-forests, feature-engineering

Feature scaling, in general, is an important stage in the data preprocessing pipeline.

Decision Tree and Random Forest algorithms, though, are scale-invariant - i.e. they work fine without feature scaling. Why is that?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?  this is a very generalized question.  Are you trying to understand the limitations of the Random Forest Classifier and Regressor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling only makes sense when there is something that reacts to that scale. Decision Trees though, just make a cut at a certain number.

Imagine: For a feature that goes from 0 to 100 a cut at 50 may be improving performance. Scaling this down to 0 to 1 making the cut a 0.5 doesn't change a thing.

Now on the other hand NN have some kind of activation function (leaving RELu aside) that react differently to input that is above 1. Here Normalization, putting every feature between 0 and 1 makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Feature scaling happens to be a problem when a model is characterized by having a distance metric (or another kind of numerical evaluation for that matter). Therefore models such as support vector machines, neural networks, distance based clustering methods (e.g. k means) and linear/logistic regression are prone to changes by feature scaling.

Those which are based on **probability** rather than distances are not scale variant. These include Naive Bayes Classifiers, or decision trees.